# HashMap con uno o varios valores en Java

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en este foro así que si no sigo alguna regla disculpen.
Mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo podría crear un HashMap que contenga uno, o varios valores?
He pensado en el ArrayList, pero quiero que cada ArrayList sea único para cada clave.

Todo esto viene por un ejercicio de 'Acepta el reto' una plataforma donde se hacen ejercicios sobre programación, os dejo el enlace del ejercicio aquí

[Ejercicio](https://www.aceptaelreto.com/pub/problems/v001/86/st/statements/Spanish/index.html)

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias explicar un poco mas? dar ejemplos?

Comment: Que has intentado sobre esto, agrega tu código, revisa [ask] saludos.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos!   @Jorgesys